# Deleting a line in file containing exact string (Python)

Tags: python, file, line

```
import re
print "List of names:"
f=open('names.txt','r')  #look below
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    info = line.split('|')
    names = info[0]
    print names
name = raw_input("Enter the name of the person you want to delete: ")
f.close()

f = open('names.txt','w')
for line in lines:
    if not re.match(name,line):
        f.write(line)
        break

print "That person doesn't exist!"
```

names.txt :

```
John|22|Nice
Johnny|55|Better than John
Peter|25|The worst
```

So, when you run the program, list of names is printed and then you have to enter the name of the person whose line you want to delete.

The problem is, if I enter John, it deletes the first and the second line, but I want only the first line to be deleted. My guess is that I'm not doing re.match() right. I tried re.match(name,names) but that doesn't work either.

So, the string you enter into `name` should be compared to the strings in `names` , and if there's an exact match, it should delete the line that has `name` as the first element.

I found a lot of similar problems but my function contains everything combined and I can't figure it out.

Comment: So, the final solution would be:
1) open in r+ mode (make sure you read everything about r+ mode)
2) name != line.partition('|')[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*re.match* matches the string at the beginning of the string. You may add word delimeter to your expression

```
name + r'\b'
```

but in your case, *re* is an overkill, simple comparison will do

```
name == line.partition('|')[0]
```

BTW, if you need to split only once at the beginning - or end - *partition* and *rpartition* functions are better options

**EDIT**

Timing:

```
    >>> timeit('line.startswith(name+"|")', 'line="John|22|Nice";name="John"')
    0.33100164101452345

    >>> timeit('line.partition("|")[0] == name', 'line="John|22|Nice";name="John"')
    0.2520693876228961

    >>> timeit('re.match(name+r"\b", line)', 'import re; line="John|22|Nice";name="John"')
1.8754496594662555

    >>> timeit('line.split("|")[0] == name', 'line="John|22|Nice";name="Jonny"') 
    0.511219799415926
```

Especially for [Padraick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)

```
>>> timeit('line.partition("|")[0] == name', 'line="John|22|Nice";name="John"')
0.27333073995099083
>>> timeit('line.split("|", 1)[0] == name', 'line="John|22|Nice";name="John"')
    0.5120651608158937
```

Frankly - I am surprised myself

Comment: Hmm something's wrong now, it kinda deletes random lines.

anyway here's the code

`f = open('names','w')
 for line in lines:
  if not name == line.partition('|')[0]:
   f.write(line)`

is this correct?

Comment: partition is no faster than using a regular split

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, depends on the length of the string. With second parameter 1 (was not in your original answer) they may be equally fast

Comment: @blazePascal, Just use another file as output - or follow Padraick's advice on input/output management

Comment: @blazePascal, you don't use `not name ==`, it would be `!=`

Comment: Working, finally! Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    name = raw_input("Enter the name of the person you want to delete: ").lower() + "|"
    ln = len(name)
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        if name == line[:ln].lower():
            lines[ind:ind+1] = []
            break
    with open("in.txt","w") as out:
        out.writelines(lines)
```

If you want to remove all John's etc.. don't break just keep looping and writing, as it stands we erase the first "John" we find. The fastest way is to just index.